# How to change the link of the logo?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have created a main site and I have created many subsite under the main site.

When I am in any main page and click on the logo icon, the page redirects to the home page.

But, when I am in any subsite and click on the logo icon, the page redirects to the subsite homepage rather than the main hompage.

I have edited on master page but no effect... [image]

Answer (score 4):

Download your masterpage and edit it. Find the following block of code (it might be somewhat different):

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=42" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

Replace SPSimpleSiteLink Tags Such that:

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">   </div>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=42" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

NavigateUrl attribute is the link you want your logo to point to

**EDIT**: Updated the code

Comment: Still its not working... I changed the code in master page in SPD.... still there is no change.... Is their any other solution?

Comment: Can you share the code you changed?

Comment: <div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl=""~sitecollection/"" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" 

LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=42" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>

Comment: NavigateUrl=""~sitecollection/"" --> Change to single quotes

Comment: Ya I removed.... Still its not working....

Comment: Updated the code. The current code works for me. Close div with id siteicon and then add the code

Comment: Have you checked in & published that master page in SPD?

Answer (score 0):

For site collection redirect option, Add the attribute NavigateUrl to this tag and set it value to "~sitecollection" For site current site redirect option, Add the attribute NavigateUrl to this tag and set it value to "~site"

```
 NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/"

 NavigateUrl="~site/"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In javascript :**

Using SP Chrome editor, upload a file in style library and script link to this js.
Edit the JS and add :

```
window.onload = function(){
Var urlLogo = "/sites/xx/xx/xx";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic").href = urlLogo;
}
```