# Change href of logo for a blank site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, site-logo, spurl

I am creating a sharepoint blank site wherein I have changed the logo image with the help of these steps https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/how-to-change-the-logo-on-your-sharepoint-2013-site/

Now, how can I change the **`href`** for this logo so that it always redirects me to the defined place.

This is a newbie's query. please cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

**By default,** the logo URL points to the home page of the current site, there is **no** any **OOTB** method to change its default URL!

---

**Workaround**

To change the logo URL,

- You will need to use The SharePoint Designer to customize the Redirect link as you prefer, check this [How to change the link of the logo?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171650/how-to-change-the-link-of-the-logo)
- Using a custom JS script as mentioned at [How to change the url for the site logo that appears on the search results page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242745/how-to-change-the-url-for-the-site-logo-that-appears-on-the-search-results-page)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the "href" to your blank site url in the code below. And add the code into master page using SharePoint designer 2013.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
$(function () {         
    myVar = setInterval(changeLogoUrl, 100);
});
function changeLogoUrl(){     
    if($(".ms-siteicon-a").length>0){
        $(".ms-siteicon-a").attr("href","http://www.bing.com");
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }   
}
</script>
```

[image]